# addView FILL_PARENT not working

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, layout-inflater

I want to put a layout into another one via layoutInflater.

Here's the main_layout.xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ads_image_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/host_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/navigation_buttons_layout"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ads_image_view" >
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/navigation_buttons_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" >


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and here's the vitrin_layout.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ff0000"
    android:text="smallred" />
```

and finally the onCreate method for my main activity:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);
    ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.host_layout);
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext()).inflate(
            R.layout.vitrin_layout, null);
    parent.addView(view, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

    setTitle(getString(R.string.title_activity_vitrin));
}
```

The problem is that the vitrin_layout, does not fit into its parent(host_layout); although I've set fill_parent where ever I could!

I can't figure out why.

Edited: I'm really sorry, but i'd pasted wrong vitrin_layout file, I fixed it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use this [addView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView%28android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams%29) method. By the way don't use `getBaseContext()` unless you know why you are using it, instead use context of an activity (`this`).

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);
    ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.host_layout);
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.vitrin_layout, null);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT); 
    parent.addView(view, params);

    setTitle(getString(R.string.title_activity_vitrin));
}
```

Comment: Anyway you are still using addView() incorectly, see the documentation for addView() method.

Answer (score 2):

```
parent.addView(view, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
```

this method was ViewGroup.addView(View child, int index) invoked actually.
you need to invoke ViewGroup.addView(View child, ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) method to set a LayoutParams.