# android listview footer change width when landscape

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I have a layout contains listview with footer, I add this footer programatically, Now I want to use landscape mode, I did everythieng, but I have a problem.

The footer in the portiet mode is fill parent width. but when I change to landscape it becomes wrape content.

help please.

#### this is how i add the footer programatically

```
View footer = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.footer_button,
                null);
        footer.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

#### landscape layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_customer_profile_title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/tv_name"
        android:textColor="#025f7c"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:typeface="serif" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="15dip" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_customer_profile_image"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="150dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:contentDescription="@string/iv_undefinedImage"
            android:paddingLeft="5dip"
            android:src="@drawable/totti" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lv_customer_profile_details"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
            android:paddingLeft="10dip"
            android:paddingRight="10dip" >
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Paste the layout code, which contains the `ListView`.

Comment: @g00dy I did .........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a similar solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11574691/addview-fill-parent-not-working):

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);
    ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.host_layout);
    View footer = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.footer_button, null);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT); 
    parent.addView(view, params);
}
```

**EDIT:**

Taking a look at the `xml`, I noticed that the `LinearLayout`, which contains the `ImageView` and the `ListView` has this:

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

If I understood corretly, this is the layout which contains the footer button and it may look like as fill_parent in portrait, but try to see it on a larger screen.

Comment: what is parent? i have listview which don't have add view function

Comment: The `parent` variable is the `ViewGroup` that your going to add the layout to, if that's convenient for your requirements. With it you can control the filling of the layout itself.

Comment: Which of the two options did you try?

Comment: Ok, one last thing I can think of: Try `footer.setFitToScreen(true);` OR `footer.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);`, If that fails, try one of the flags here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

Comment: would you follow me please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17468095/android-listview-footer-width-changed-to-match-parent-itself

Comment: Sure, I posted a comment there.

Answer (score 0):

Try manually setting the layouyt parameters for the view, to ensure its set to fill_parent for its width.

Comment: would you follow me please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17468095/android-listview-footer-width-changed-to-match-parent-itself