# android listview footer width changed to match parent itself

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I have an activity with portrait and landscape  mode.

the activity contains listview. this listview has a footer, which I added programmatically like this:

```
View footer = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.footer_button,
                null);
        footer.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
lv_details.addFooterView(footer);
```

and the layout for the footer `footer_button.xml` is:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/b_ok"
        android:text="@string/b_ok"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_selector"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

that works perfectly with the portrait mode. 
 image when the footer (ok button) is correct
[image]

Now when I go to landscape mode, I got the problem.
here is what the footer became
[image]

I go into the Hierachy viewer and I think I found the error, look at this photo please
[image]
as you see, the width is `Match parent` not `fill parent` even though I have used `fill parent` in my layout.

what is the solution please?

**Code after someone asked to**

```
adapter = new AdapterFoodProfile(this, aList);
        View header = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(
                R.layout.customer_profile_header, null);
        tv_edit = (TextView) header
                .findViewById(R.id.tv_customer_profile_header_edit);
        tv_edit.setOnClickListener(this);
        lv_details.addHeaderView(header);
        View footer = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.footer_button,
                null);
        footer.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
        b_ok = (Button) footer.findViewById(R.id.b_ok);
        b_ok.setOnClickListener(this);
        lv_details.addFooterView(footer);
        lv_details.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: I saw, that you're adding the button (the layout) to the `ListView` - lv_details. Can you share the code of it, it might be controlling the child view ;-)

Comment: I will add the code, wait please

Comment: @g00dy look there is something interesting, I am using `null` in the viewgroup, is this correct?

Comment: Exacly my point from the first comment. Share the new problem in a few words, in a chat maybe ?

Comment: @g00dy what? i didn't understand what you said, would you explain please?

Comment: I think I saw a comment here, stating that the `ListView` has been set to `android:layout_width="fill_parent"` - no ? And then some other problems occur?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this fixes the problem, even partially, as you did - the `ListView` has been set to `android:layout_width="fill_parent"`. If another problem occurs it will be related to this one indirectly.

Answer (score 0):

Please set button width fill_parent.